# How can I isolate suspicious executables witout deleting them?

Tags: windows, malware, virus

Windows Defender is always notifying me about some malware but it can't delete it.
I know that executable (it's a testing virus). So how can I isolate that, so Windows Defender can't find it anymore and if the virus really contains malware that it can't do anything to my computer?
Shall I create an archive?
Please help
Thanks, K.NaN

Comment: The way to go is to create a password protected archive

Comment: OK, I though about that but I wasn't really sure if this is secure, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would use is a virtual machine with Windows Defender turned off. Overall, having a malicious executable on your actual PC is not a good idea and you should always do this kind of testing on a disposable virtual machine.